# Chrome doesn't save Express cookie in React app

Tags: reactjs, express, google-chrome, cookies, cross-domain

I am receiving cookies from my Express app with no warnings, however the cookie never gets stored (confirmed via Chrome dev tools).

I have setup a React app and express API:

**api:**
`https://api.mycompany.com` (`express: 4.17.1`)

**app:** `https://app.mycompany.com`
(`react 17.0.2` with `superagent` HTTP lib.)

In my React code I'm making a request to `https://api.mycompany.com/get_cookie`:

```
// setup the agent ...
const agent = request
      .agent()
      .use(prefix('https://api.mycompany.com'))
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

// make the request (confirmed response OK)
await agent
      .post('/get_cookie')
      .send(queryParams)
      .withCredentials();
```

I see the cookie in the response headers (with no warnings!)

```
Set-Cookie: my_token=<token-content>; Max-Age=604800; Path=/; Expires=Sat, 21 Aug 2021 14:17:13 GMT; Secure; SameSite=None
```

On my server (`https://api.mycompany.com`):

**Setup CORS**

```
app.use(cors({
  origin: true, // reflect request origin
  credentials: true
}));
app.options('*', cors());  // enable pre-flight?
```

**Send the cookie**

```
// from /get_cookie:

res.cookie('my_token',
  JSON.stringify(<token-content>),
  {
    maxAge: 10 * 60_000, // 10 mins
    httpOnly: false,
    signed: true,
    secure: true,
    sameSite: 'none'
  });
```

Having a really hard time with this one and at a bit of a loss  Why doesn't my browser store the cookie? I've tested in Firefox and I have the same problem. Any help would be much appreciated!!

[image: Requests]

[image: No cookies]

[image: Cookie received]

Comment: Are you sure that you're checking cookies on ```https://api.mycompany.com``` domain not on your react app domain? If you're using chrome then go to ```chrome://settings/siteData``` and search your server domain.

Comment: @AsadJivani I just had a look and all I see is "app.company.com locally stored data"

Comment: Strange, This might be related to domain mix up, have you tried passing the domain as your cookie property like ```domain: '.yourcompany.com'```, this will allow all sub-domain to use your cookies.

Comment: @AsadJivani Just attempted this - Still no luck.

Comment: Can you attach your request and response headers snapshot?

Comment: Have you checked the cookie tab along with the header tab in chrome? This helps if there is any issue with your cookie format.

Comment: Added a picture of the cookie from the cookie tab.

Comment: Well, I have covered pretty much everything tbh, but one last thing you could try is to switch from superagent to Axios or fetch API, hope it will help. Best of Luck.

Comment: @AsadJivani I managed to figure out the solution, but your troubleshooting helped a lot, so thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

I moved the `withCredentials()` call to the agent itself. For some reason, this did the trick:

```
const agent = request
      .agent()
      .use(prefix('https://api.mycompany.com'))
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
      .withCredentials();
```